# Функция с переменным количеством параметров в Си

Tags: c++, c, функции

Необходимо «конвертировать» код программы из С++ в С.

Условие задачи:

> Написать функцию с переменным количеством параметров. Первым параметром передавать количество последующих параметров. Функция принимает символы. Сформировать строку из переданных символов. Если очередной символ - '#', то предыдущий символ в строку не включать (например, для "asd# 89yui##" результатом будет "as 89y") - решётки тоже не включаются в строку.

Код:

```cpp
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    template<typename... Args>
    string fn(Args... args)
    {
        auto seq = initializer_list<char>({ args... });
        string str;
        for (auto ch : seq)
        {
            if (ch == '#' && !str.empty()) str.pop_back();
            else str += ch;
        }
        return str;
    }
    
    int main() 
    {
        auto str = fn('a', 's', 'd', '#', ' ', '8', '9', 'y', 'u', 'i', '#', '#');
        cout << str << '\n';
        system("pause > nul");
    }
```

Comment: [man stdarg](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg), [man realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)

Comment: В вашем примере, нет никакого переменного числа параметров, т.к. функция будет содержать определенное кол-во параметров.

Comment: @mik.ov, как это нет, если есть?

Comment: Там же число параметров будет известно на этапе компиляции

Comment: @mik.ov, а разве оно не всегда известно при компиляции? Суть в том, что функция должна уметь принимать сколько угодно. По крайней мере в сишном варианте, а то на плюсах будет куча функций под параметры.

Comment: @Qwertiy, В случае си, нет, функция не будет знать сколько ей передали, а в случае шаблона, да.

Comment: @mik.ov, но в мете вызова будет известно всегда? Ведь нет возможности подсунуть что-то типа спреда массива в си?

Answer (score 4):

> Написать функцию с переменным количеством параметров.

Процитирую документацию:

```
void va_start(va_list argptr, last_parm)
void va_end(va_list argptr)
void va_arg(va_list argptr, type)
```

Прототип в:

*stdarg.h*

Описание:

Макросы *va_arg(), va_start()* и *va_end()* используются совместно для того, чтобы осуществить передачу функции переменного числа параметров. Наиболее общеупотребительным примером ис­пользования функции с переменным числом параметров служит *printr()*. Тип *va_list* определен в файле *stdarg.h*.

Общая процедура создания функции, которая имеет переменное число аргументов, заключает­ся в следующем: функция должна иметь один или более известных параметров. Эти известные параметры следуют перед списком переменных параметров. Самый правый известный параметр называется *last_parm*. Имя *last_parm* используется в качестве второго параметра в вызове *va_start()*. Прежде чем осуществлять доступ к какому-либо из переменных параметров, должен быть иници­ализирован указатель *argptr*, для чего используется вызов *va_start()*. После этого параметры воз­вращаются с помощью вызова функции *va_arg()* с параметром *type*, являющимся типом следующе­го параметра. Наконец, после того, как все параметры прочитаны, перед тем как выйти из функции, необходимо вызвать функцию *va_end()*, что гарантирует правильное восстановление стека. Если функция *va_end()* не вызвана, то возникает аварийная ситуация.

Пример:

Следующая программа использует функцию sum_series() для возврата суммы последовательности чисел. Первый аргумент содержит счетчик числа аргументов, которые будут переданы функции.

В данном примере суммируются первые пять элементов последовательности:

(1/2)+(1/4)+(1/8)+(1/16) ...

Программа выведет результат «0.968750».

```
/* пример аргумента переменной длины - сумма последовательности */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
double sum_series(int, ...);

int main(void)
{
    double d;
    d = sum_series(5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125);
    printf("Sum of series is %f\n",d);
    return 0;
}

double sum_series(int num, ...)
{
    double sum = 0.0, t;
    va_list argptr;

    /* инициализация argptr */
    va_start (argptr, num);

    /* сумма последовательности */
    for(; num; num—) {
        t = va_arg(argptr,double);
        sum += t;
    }

    /* завершение */
    va_end(argptr);
    return sum;
}
```